# How do I get to an "open with" menu?

Tags: menu

If I right click, or double right click, I don't get an open with menu. Also, if this helps you answer, when I play minecraft, it identifies a right click as a left click.

Comment: How is your mouse configured in settings? What happens if you plug in a different mouse?

Comment: I use a touchpad. My mouse is configured just fine, I believe.

Comment: What program are you using to try to get the "open with" menu? What computer are you using? Does right click work in any other applications? Can you add a picture of your touchpad and associated buttons?